# Searching for lower case letter in notepad++

Tags: search, notepad++

In Notepad++, is there a special char I could use in search to only give me letters which are lower cased?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notepad++ supports searching regular expressions.  You can search for [a-z] in your file.  This will find any single lower case character.

You expand the regular expression to make it more specific - such as a certain # of lower case characters.

Comment: I've made the edits. I meant to say that I'm looking for a special char that would represent any lower case letter, such as \d represents a general digit.

Comment: No.  Regular expression languages do not have a character class for this.  They have one for "word characters", but that would include uppercase and some others.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses. This question is only a few votes away from being closed. I didn't know what needed elaboration.